# TABLE_NAME as parameter in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Looks for suggestions to pass table name as parameter in Oracle store procedure

Ex:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <procedure name>
( 
<table name> IN VARCHAR2
) IS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO table1 
  (
    SELECT * FROM schema.<table name from parameter>
    MINUS
    SELECT * FROM table2);

END;
```

Comment: You need to use dynamic programming to use a table name this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892047/how-to-pass-a-table-name-as-parameter-to-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this, you'd need to use dynamic SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sample_procedure( p_table_name IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  l_sql_stmt := 
    'INSERT INTO table1 ' ||
    '  (SELECT * FROM schema.' || p_table_name ||
    '   MINUS ' ||
    '   SELECT * FROM table2) ';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
END;
```

Of course, the fact that you have many tables whose structure exactly matches that of `table1` and `table2` and whose data can meaningfully be used in this sort of `MINUS` operation strongly implies that you have an underlying data model issue that ought to be fixed.  Using dynamic SQL is likely just putting a bandage on this fundamental problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that dynamic SQL is re-parsed every time it is called, whereas static, compiled and parameterized SQL in a stored procedure may be parsed only once for many, perhaps thousands of executions. So if your SQL is getting executed frequently or a large number of times, there could be a performance hazard to using dynamic SQL.