# How to pass the value of procedure to select statement in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a procedure where I am calling the procedure using

```
exec ot.selector('regions');
```

But,I am getting error at this line:

```
 select * from ot."||p_table_name||";
```

So the procedure I tried to make was:

```
 create or replace procedure ot.selector(p_table_name varchar2)
    is
    cursor cur is
    select * from ot."||p_table_name||";
    begin
    for i in cur
    loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i.region_name);
    end loop;
    end;
```

The error I got is :

```
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 1, column 10:
PLS-00905: object OT.SELECTOR is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The error I got after making procedure is :

```
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
4/19    PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name
4/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
 (1: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
```

Comment: Show us the error please. Thanks!

Comment: changes made please see the error

Comment: That is the error what you get when you try to call the procedure...

Comment: ok just refresh the page again

Answer (score 2):

Here's a *working* alternative; see if it helps.

As you didn't provide test case, I'm creating the REGIONS table out of Scott's DEPT.

```
SQL> create table regions as
  2    select deptno, loc as region_name from dept;

Table created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure selector(p_table_name in varchar2) as
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3    rc    sys_refcursor;
  4    l_rc  regions%rowtype;
  5  begin
  6    l_str := 'select * from ' || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(p_table_name);
  7
  8    open rc for l_str;
  9    loop
 10      fetch rc into l_rc;
 11      exit when rc%notfound;
 12      dbms_output.put_line(l_rc.region_name);
 13    end loop;
 14    close rc;
 15  end;
 16  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec selector('regions');
NEW YORK
DALLAS
CHICAGO
BOSTON

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you wonder what's `DBMS_ASSERT` used for, it is here to prevent SQL injection (as mentioned within comments). If you pass anything that is not valid, you'd get

```
SQL> exec selector('nonexistent_table');
BEGIN selector('nonexistent_table'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-44002: invalid object name
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 316
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.SELECTOR", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Comment: Ok, so the table OP is passing needs to be same(number and type of columns) as regions table ? Just curious. Thanks for the answer in advance!

Comment: @VBokšić: From my point of view, the whole *story* is quite useless. It will work **only** for tables that contain a column named REGION_NAME. Everything else will fail. Who wants to create such a function? Its usability is very restricted. I'd understand if the OP wanted to pass both table and column name, but this ... I don't know what requirement stands behind it, maybe it is some kind of a homework or what. No idea.

Comment: thank you for your answer. That was what I was thinking too. I have researched is it possible to send a "p_table_name" and then make everything else dynamically - even this: "l_rc  regions%rowtype".  I have come to a conclusion it is not possible :) heheh (well at least in time I have to attack this subject). I will give you vote up because I believe your answer gives the best view on the entire subject on hand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dynamic sql` for cursor.

```
create or replace procedure ot.selector(p_table_name varchar2)
    is
    cur sys_refcursor;
    V_sql varchar2(4000);
    v_rec SOME_TABLE%ROWTYPE; -- add variable table name here
    begin
    V_sql := 'select * from ot.'|| p_table_name;
    Open cur for v_sql;
    LOOP
  FETCH CUR INTO v_rec;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_rec.region_name);
  EXIT WHEN v_rec%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
    Close cur;
    end;
    end selector;
    /
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This implementation is open to SQL injection attacks. Validating the `p_table_name` is a valid database object would help in securing the code.

Comment: How do you do this part :  v_rec SOME_TABLE%ROWTYPE; -- add variable table name here ?

Answer (score -1):

Your line:

```
 select * from ot."||p_table_name||";
```

should look like this:

```
 select * from ot. || p_table_name;
```

This `||` is a concatenate sign.

Hope that this will help...

Comment: @VBoksic just want to understand how can you call procedure in select statment

Comment: @Andrew OP is not doing that. He wants to send a parameter to a procedure so the procedure can make a select. Maybe I am wrong. In that case I will delete this coment and stop editing it :) Sorry

Comment: I again tried v_new_table varchar2(255) := 'OT.'|| p_table_name;  and  select * from v_new_table; but it is still showing me error

Comment: @KarkiAshwin there is a lot of work on this one. Not even sure if you can do it. Check this here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892047/how-to-pass-a-table-name-as-parameter-to-stored-procedure

Comment: Great, again a down vote ?! It says: This answer is not useful! How it is not useful ? It is still active and with this answer we have corrected one line of code and we are going in the correct direction... I do not understand this... If it is vote down please explain why ?